# Android - get the id of a parent view as laid in the activity/fragment

Tags: android, view, casting, onclicklistener, parent

So, I've seen several posts here that suggest that the best solution to get the id of a parent view of any child view in Android is something of the like:

```
View parent = (View)child.getParent();
int id = parent.getId();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work in my case. I have a custom ViewGroup (extends FrameLayout) with 2 buttons, a textView and a bar that need to be updated on button clicks.

```
class WaveControl extends FrameLayout{
    Button minus;
    Button plus;
    ExpandingBar bar; //simple view that only draws a color(need for indication purposes)
    int counter;
  }
```

The expanding bar needs to be animated on button clicks and I have methods that take care of that inside WaveControl. I also have a fragment that has five WaveControls and I need to implement an onClickListener in the fragment to apply a filter depending on which of the WaveControls was clicked/updated. BUT even if I implement the above code I get different ids, i.e. as in:

```
WaveControl wc1; // (in xml id is field_1)
WaveControl wc2; // (in xml if is field_2)
WaveControl wc3; //...
WaveControl wc4; //...

wc1.minus.setOnclickListener(this);
wc2.plus.setOnclickListener(this);
.... //this for every button

@Override
public void OnClick(View v){
    View parent = (View)v.getParent();
    int id = parent.getId();
    Log.i(TAG, "view id: "+ id +"   wc1 id: " + field1.getId());
    switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.minus:
          ...
    }
 }
```

The output is: `I/WaveFragment﹕ view id: -1   wc1 id: 2131624083`
Clearly this can't serve me as an indicator which was the view being clicked.
I have figured a workaround in just making several onClickListeners for each waveControl field, but it doesn't seem like the perfect solution.
And still the problem is there : casting a ViewParent to a View will not get you the actual id of the view as laid in the fragment. Any prompts why this is happening would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing "id"s, comparing the "views" will probably work. 
For this, you should initialize the views you will compare. 
For example:

```
View minus = (View) wc1.findViewById(R.id.minus); //or wc1.minus
switch(v){
       case minus:
...
}
```

Edit:
In your code, you are comparing a view's id with a view. I guess comparing both ids will solve your problem.

> ```
> @Override
> public void OnClick(View v){
>     View parent = (View)v.getParent();
>     int id = parent.getId();
>     Log.i(TAG, "view id: "+ id +"   wc1 id: " + field1.getId());
>     switch(v.getId()){
>        case wc1.minus.getId():
>           ...
>       case wc1.plus.getId():
>           ...
>       case wc2.minus.getId():
>           ...
>       case wc2.plus.getId():
>           ...
>
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it correctly. I need to see which is the parent of the button because the different waveControls change different parts of a signal. In that sense I can easily discriminate between plus or minus but I can't tell who is the parent. Not with a single onclicklistener at least.